# Вылетает Visual Studio 2017 при добавлении таблицы в БД

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Создаю БД в Visual Studio 2017, потом создаю в ней таблицу, нажимаю кнопку "Обновить", чтобы сохранить таблицу и у меня вылетает студия. Что делать?

Comment: та же проблема, искал ответ, не нашел(

Answer (score 0):

Люди, нужно просто установить Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools! 
Вот ссылка:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer

Comment: Почему вы так думаете?

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/303306)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, предлагаешь основные байты из exe'шника в ответ скопипастить? ;)

Comment: Понял, понял, не ругайте так сильно =). Скорее всего проблема в том что у людей не установлены необходимые пакеты MVS. У самого так было, решил проблему до установив необходимые пакеты.